# .htaccess mod rewrite causing strange error with form action url on remote server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am not sure if the problem is the .htaccess file but it is what my hosting company are telling me.

I have used a framework called Perch for a site I am building which I have tweaked to work how I want it to for a shopping cart area on the site. The site works fine on my local server (MAMP) but since I have uploaded to my remote server I am having a problem adding an item to the cart (using a straight forward form post action whilst testing and getting it to work).

My .htaccess file includes all of the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^dog-agility-equipment/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /dog-agility-equipment/category.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^agility-equipment/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /dog-agility-equipment/product.php?s=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^agility-equipment/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /dog-agility-equipment/product.php?s=$1 [L]
```

The form action [url] is

/manage/addons/apps/perch_shop_paypal/cart.functions.php

And the server is trying to direct to the url

http://site-name.uk/manage/?r=%2Fmanage%2Faddons%2Fapps%2Fperch_shop_paypal%2Fcart.functions.php

I have never seen this before and can't see why my .htaccess file would be causing this issue (especially as it doesn't happen on my local server).

Does anyone know why this is happening, what am I missing?

Comment: I would rather suggest to not believe the hosting company and make sure that your remote installation is not lacking the [Perch Shop App Paypal](https://docs.grabaperch.com/addons/shop-paypal/).

Comment: Syck, I have to agree with you about not believing the hosting company but I don't know how else I can get them to help me sort the problem if they are insisting it is not the server but my .htaccess. I have checked all the folders and files and they are all there, plus I have checked the permissions which are also all correct.

Comment: Do you use your own installation of perch or is it supplied by your hosting provider? In the first case, you should confirm that the shop-app add-on to perch is installed and working, in the latter one, you should ask your hosting company to do so. Did you try disabling the rewrites? As I understand them, they are only for convenience but not required to run the site. If it still shows up that error message, confront the support of the hosting provider with the fact. If not, try to find the malicious rule by deactivating the conds & rules one by one.

Comment: It is my own installation (and, as I say it works fine on localhost) that I have uploaded to my remote server for client to view and test etc. All the required folders and files are there (I have checked) and I know it is all working properly as otherwise the shop area wouldn't even display the categories and products. I can't disable the rewrites as otherwise the categories and products don't display as the rewrites are being used to create friendly URLs (so yes, in a sense they are required for the site to work).